# Setting Up Symfony Dev Environment in Heroku

Tags: macos, apache, symfony, heroku

So as the title suggests, I am setting up a Symfony project in heroku.  It is on my Mac OSX laptop.  I followed [the directions here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony) to set it up.  I got everything installed, pushed my project to heroku, tested it and it works on the web.

Now I'm trying to set up the local dev environment.  I would like to be able to simply use `heroku local` to launch the dev server as usual.  I installed the [heroku php buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php), and I created a `Procfile` with these contents:

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

the `composer config bin-dir` command returns `vendor/bin`, and then I can see that `heroku-php-apache2` file in there.  Everything looks good.

When I run `heroku local` I get this error:

```
[WARN] No ENV file found 
15:48:49 web.1   |  This program requires Apache 2.4.10 or newer with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi enabled; check your 'httpd' command. 
15:48:49 web.1   Exited with exit code 1
```

So I checked the `httpd -v` and I have:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix) 
Server built:   Oct  3 2017 10:26:24
```

I just enabled (uncommented) `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_fcgi` in the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file and restarted the machine, but still seeing the same error.  I am starting to think it is a problem with my Procfile or something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having a similar problem, I was able to fix the issue.  The issue WAS that I edited the wrong `httpd.conf` file, since I installed the apache from homebrew.

The path `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is correct if you are using the default apache2 installation on the mac.  If you installed apache from homebrew like I did, you will find the httpd.conf file at `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`.

You need to uncomment the 2 lines for `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_fcgi` and also uncomment the port listener directive, since heroku likes to listen on non-default port 5000 and heroku will automatically do that at run time.

Also the server cannot be running already when you use `heroku local`.

:-)

Comment: Working for me. With a bit of help from https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/install_the_mod_proxy_http_connector_into_apache_httpd